# reading old hardrive on new computer access is denied

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7: Can't access or delete folder although logged in as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/305019/windows-7-cant-access-or-delete-folder-although-logged-in-as-administrator)

I get a message saying "access is denied" for a hard drive I am trying to transfer old data off of. How to I get the correct permissions to access the files in windows 7?
*I also cannot change the owner access is also denied. Is something wrong with the drive possibly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a Elevated CMD window (right click CMD select "run as administrator")

type: `net user administrator /active:yes`

Then log off and back in as the administrator. Copy your files, change ownership, ect.

Make sure you turn this account off when you are done as it by passes UAC and is a security risk, just substitute active:yes for active:no.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and choose your answer if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take ownership of the files. There is a [great tutorial](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm) how to do this.

Comment: He said access is denied to change ownership... this happens sometimes when trying to transfer files from a drive running XP or earlier in Windows 7.

Comment: I have full control of both the user and the folder, and I still get access denied. Im stuck.

Comment: Try doing a file system check if that didn't help. Maybe theres something wrong with either the file system or even the hard drive. Never had problem with taking ownership! You have administrator rights, don't you? (UAC is fine)